# Retornar una variable que esta dentro de un ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Busco la forma de mostrar un `child.rows` pero de la unica forma que se puede mostrar es con un `return`directo.
entonces hice este codigo para que por fuera del ajax me tome esos valores pero no me da, espero que me puedan ayudar.

**CODIGO**

```
        function format (data) {
         $.ajax({
           url: "list_data",
           type: 'POST', 
           data: {'data':data[0]}, 
           success: function (result){
             for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){ 
               var resultado =  '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
                '<tr>'+
                  '<td>Full name:result[i].nombre</td>'+
                  '<td></td>'+
                '</tr>'+
               '</table>';
             }
             return resultado;
           }
         });
        }
```

**return resultado;** esto es lo que pienso que esta malo, y como ven necesito retornar ese codigo dentro del for y si hago el return dentro del for no funciona tiene que ser fuera del metodo ajax.

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );
```

Comment: Hola, has intentado hacerlo con callbacks o promesas? así envías los datos donde se escribe en html.

Comment: No, no he manejo callbacks ni promesas :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Por su naturaleza asíncrona, no puedes hacer que tu función retorne un valor desde el `success` de `ajax`; tienes que manejarlo dentro del `success`.**

Puedes hacerlo, por ejemplo, de la siguiente forma:

```
// Se agrega el parámetro "callback", que debe ser una función
function format (data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "list_data",
        type: 'POST', 
        data: {'data':data[0]}, 
        success: function (result){
            for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){ 
                var resultado =  '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
                    '<tr>'+
                    '<td>Full name:result[i].nombre</td>'+
                    '<td></td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                    '</table>';
            }
            // Tras obtener tu resultado, ejecutas la función recibida
            // como parámetro, con "resultado" como argumento
            callback(resultado);
        }
    });
}
```

Y en tu código principal, llamas a tu función `format` así:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        format(row.data(), function(resultado){
            // "resultado" contiene la cadena que necesitas retornar
            row.child(resultado).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        });
    }
} );
```

Comment: el ultimo trozo de codigo debo de insertarlo en esta funcion.. row.child( format(row.data())).show();
         tr.addClass('shown');he tratado muchas formas y no me funciona sabes depronto de que manera?

Comment: @Daniel ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar el código donde llamas a la función `format`? ¿Eso lo llamas dentro de otra función, o cómo?

Comment: listo voy a editarla

Comment: @Daniel Actualicé mi respuesta con la forma en que deberías llamar a la función `format` para obtener el resultado.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho el codigo funciona bien,solo hay un pequeño problema y es el ciclo for, el cual no funciona, solamente trae un solo dato.

Comment: @Daniel El ciclo `for` es independiente de tu pregunta (cómo retornar el resultado de una llamada ajax). Si hay algún problema en el ciclo, puede tener que ver con los datos que tienes o con el código en ese ciclo en particular. Recuerda que en este sitio cada pregunta es una sola pregunta (valga la redundancia); si no logras resolver el problema con el ciclo `for` y quieres preguntarlo en este sitio, haz una nueva pregunta con tu nuevo problema.

Comment: listo  @Rodrigo Salgado Atala igualmente te agradezco por la ayuda el codigo me ha servido de la manera que requeria.